# how to compile a java package in linux command

Tags: java, linux

I have 2 java files, (main.java, Test.java) Inside each file I write package adt;

I write a class called ADT inside main.java, and I call the class ADT in my Test.java.

I want to compile the Test.java,

Inside command line I wrote javac ~/Desktop/adt/Test.java

but I got error saying cannot find ADT, symbol: ADT, location: Test.java

Can anyone help me?

Comment: In Java, the code for a class named `ADT` must stand in a file named `ADT.java`. You can't declare a class other that `Main` in `Main.java` :)

Comment: Not completely true... you can't declare an additional `public` class other than `Main` in `Main.java`, though (implicitly) private classes are valid

Answer (score 0):

As your `Test.java` refers to `ADT` class so you need to first compile your `main.java` as that contains `ADT` class.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `ADT` class to be called from `Test`, then `ADT` will need to be a public java class and there fore will need to be in its own java file i.e. `ADT.java`.

The `ADT` will then need to be compiled first.

Answer (score 0):

usually source file should be name after class name, so class `ADT` should be in `ADT.java`

if you declare `ADT` class inside `main.java` - you need to declare it as `public static` and in `Test.java` refer as `main.ADT`

in both cases you should compile both files with main/adt file first